# How to achieve this lighting?

Tags: lighting

How to get this lighting? Is it due to camera or photo editing? It seems it is edited later.
[image]

Comment: What are you seeing in the image that you are describing as "this lighting"? There are several things going on here, and it's impossible for us to guess which you are concerned with. Please edit your question (including the title) to be more specific.

Comment: [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3881/15871)

Comment: [What's the best way to ask a “How do I achieve this effect?” question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/677/15871)

Answer (score 7):

It's an on camera flash outputting at a higher color temperature (bluer) than the ambient lighting behind the two main subjects. The flash appears to be a typical 5500-6000K or so full spectrum light. The background appears to be more limited spectrum lighting centered on about 3700-3000K such as is typical with older tubular fluorescent lighting.

The camera appears to have been set to match the color temperature of the flash. This makes the ambient light look yellow/orange. If the color was adjusted to match the light source in the background, the two main subjects would appear very blue.

Comment: I'm voting this up, but I'm also waiting for the original poster to come back and say "huh? What are you talking about? I mean the shiny glow on the fabric, obviously. None of this color temperature stuff!"

Comment: @mattdm Don't hold your breath while you wait for the OP to update the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can see from the shadows under the chins and the highlight reflections off the flat skin facing the camera, that there is a bright point-ish light a little above and left of the camera.  This by itself should immediately suggest a pop-up flash on a point and shoot camera.

The "snapshot" nature of the picture suggests a photographer likely to use a point and shoot camera.  These kinds of cameras often have integrated flashes.

The color analysis by Michael Clark also strongly points to a flash.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the building ends close to where the subjects are standing (ie. they are illuminated by daylight), but as Michael suggests a flash is most likely. It doesn't look like post production to me.